# Wix PUT function after updating value in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-api, put, velo, sql-update

Need to update values in wix database after same values are updated in an google spreadsheet.

Wrote PUT function to update the data but keeps returning with a 500 error. Any suggestions?

```html
export function put_updaterecords (request) {

  return request.body.json()
 .then(body => {
  let recordUpdate = {
           "_id": body.ID, 
      "title": body.Title, 
            "firstName": body.FirstName,
            "lastName": body.LastName,
      "color": body.Color,
      "number": body.Number
  };

    return wixData.insert('GoogleSheetstoWixDatabase', recordUpdate)
  .then(result => ok({body: JSON.stringify(result)}))
  .catch(err => response({status: 500, body: err}));
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your permissions on the dataset, make sure it's set to 'any' for the view/create field.  I had this same issue.

What this code doesn't do (I'm assuming you got it from wixshow like me) is it doesn't allow data-in-place updates, meaning any time there's a change to a field, it adds new rows instead of updating existing ones.  If anyone can shed light on using wixData.update in place of .insert that would be helpful...

Comment: Yes! I realised that too and I changed the settings for the database to any. Thanks for the suggestion. Will close the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution in the end. Had overlooked the settings of the database. Changed settings to update the database to allow and it worked.